# change js popup name

Tags: javascript, html, popup

i made a js popup, and it need to give a name after it pops up, here is my code for it, the second argument i assigned the blank, so i need set second argument after this popup launched

```
pp=window.open('demo/player.php','','width=200,height=100');
```

i need to change the popup name to "firstpp" after it opened
something like "firstpp" for second argument as below
, **can i give pp.name ... or something like**

```
pp=window.open('demo/player.php','firstpp ','width=200,height=100');
```

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently not tested, but you should be able to use the following so long as the popup is in the same domain as the main window:

```
var pp = window.open('demo/player.php','','width=200,height=100');

// some time later:
pp.name = 'firstpp';
```

Comment: oops this is working ;) thank you.... 
i attack to google chrome popup blocker ;)